# How to test code before a suspended coroutine function

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, coroutine

Consider the following example in a view model class:

```
    override fun signInViewSelected(
        email: String,
        password: String
    ) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            loadingViewState.value = LoadingState.Loading("Loading")

            withContext(dispatcher.ioDispatcher) {
                authManager.signIn(email, password) // suspend fun signIn(email: String, password: String): Boolean -> makes network call
            }

            loadingViewState.value = LoadingState.NotLoading
        }
    }
```

How could I test this method so that I can verify that I start out in loading state, call the authManager.signIn method, and then end up in the not loading state?

When I had this setup with completion handlers I was able to capture the argument passed to my mock `authManager` class, and then call that manually to advance the completion, but with coroutines I'm not familiar with how to do the equivalent behavior.

What I'd want is something like this, ideally:

```
    @Test
    fun `sign in loading state`() {
        signInViewModel.signInViewSelected("email@email.com", "password")

        val inProgressLoadingViewState = signInViewModel.loadingViewState.getOrAwaitValue()
        assertLoadingStateIsLoading(inProgressLoadingViewState, progressMessage)

        // delay mockAuthManager until now, have it execute at this point

        val finishedLoadingViewState = signInViewModel.loadingViewState.getOrAwaitValue()
        assertLoadingStateIsNotLoading(finishedLoadingViewState)
    }
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're familiar with libraries like AssertJ and Mockito, I would go about it the following way:

First off, mock the observer of `loadingViewState` (assuming you have some LiveData in place) and `authManager`:

```
private lateinit var viewModel: SomeViewModel
private val loadingViewStateObserver = mock<Observer<LoadingViewState>>()

fun initViewModel() {

    viewModel = SomeViewModel().apply {
        loadingViewStateLiveData.observeForever(loadingViewStateObserver)
    }
}
```

```
@Test
fun `sign in loading state`() {
    runBlocking {
        initViewModel()
        viewModel.signInViewSelected("email", "password")
    
        inOrder(loadingViewStateObserver, authManager) {
           verify(loadingViewStateObserver).onChanged(LoadingState.NotLoading)
           verify(authManager).signIn("email", "password")
           verify(loadingViewStateObserver).onChanged(LoadingState.Loading("Loading"))
        }
    }
}
```